# How do I test that PyVista successfully plotted a figure?

Tags: python, pyvista

I am generating 3D meshes in PyVista, and I would like to update my integration test suite to ensure that it successfully shows my plots.

I'm hoping to adapt the methodology described [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/unit-testing-python-data-visualizations-18e0250430), to work with PyVista. Unfortunately, I can't find any results for any equivalent function to plt.gcf() in PyVista.

Does anyone know of a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few ways of doing this.  First, `pyvista` returns a instance of `pyvista.plotting.renderer.CameraPosition` upon a successful plot.  For example:

```py
>>> import pyvista
>>> sphere = pyvista.Sphere()
>>> cpos = sphere.plot(off_screen=True)
>>> print(type(cpos))
<class 'pyvista.plotting.renderer.CameraPosition'>
```

Since it's necessary to setup a plot and renderer to properly display a plot, getting a return camera position means that your plot was successful.

Alternatively, you can save the screenshot and check that the file exists:

```py
import os
import pyvista
sphere = pyvista.Sphere()
cpos = sphere.plot(off_screen=True, screenshot='tmp.png')
assert os.path.isfile('tmp.png')
```

You could also check the content of the saved image as well (or potentially file size)